# C# - using value twice within object initialiser

Tags: c#, linq, initialization

I have the below code I would like to adapt because it is calling multiple times on a lengthy event that I think could be avoided:

```
People= (from p in xDocument.Root.Descendants("People").Where(
                        se => Get<int>(se.Element("ID")) != i1)
          select new Person
              {
                 ID = Get<int>(se.Element("ID")),
                 Skills = GetPersonSkills(Get<int>(se.Element("ID")))
              }).OrderBy(w => w.FirstName).ToList()
```

How can I, instead of having the application rerun the Get(se.Element("ID")) method, just simply tell `Skills = GetPersonSkills(ID)`. It would then just simply read its own ID value.

PS: The code I wrote here is not the actual lengthy code but simplified to demonstrate the purpose. I am aware that my Get(se.Element("ID")) example is not time consuming for the application but it was just to highlight the part of teh code that i would need to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in an anonymous type:

```
People= xDocument.Root.Descendants("People")
    .Select(se => new { ID=Get<int>(se.Element("ID")) })
    .Where(x => x.ID != i1)
    .Select(x => new Person
          {
             ID = x.ID,
             Skills = GetPersonSkills(x.ID)
          }
    ).OrderBy(w => w.FirstName)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
People = xDocument.Root.Descendats("People")
    .Select(se => Get<int>(se.Element("ID")))
    .Where(id => id != i1)
    .Select(id => new Person
        {
            ID = id,
            Skills = GetPersonSkills(id)
        })
    .OrderBy(w => w.FirstName)
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass whatever `Get<int>(se.Element("ID"))` returns to the `Person` constructor, and have the constructor fill in its `ID` and `Skills` properties.